# jQuery Custom Calculator with Static Arrays

Tags: jquery

I might lost in this part to use a multiple array to match my Unit over Size with static value inside array. What i wanted to do here is to make each radio represent an amount that matches the selections.

For example, If I clicked Low (Unit) while staying at 8 sq meters (Size), static value from Array should be 320 000... and so on. Same as at the Size section.

```
$(function(){
    $("form #calc-standard li").each(function (i) {
        i = i+1;
        $(this).addClass("item"+i);

        // Temporary pattern
        var eightSqm = ["260 000", "320 000", "400 000"];

        // Main pattern
        var prices = [
            ["160 000", "210 000", "260 000", "310 000", "370 000"],
            ["190 000", "250 000", "320 000", "380 000", "440 000"],
            ["250 000", "310 000", "400 000", "480 000", "560 000"]
        ];

        $("#calc-standard input[type='radio']").on("change", function(){
            if( $(this).val() == $(this).data('unit') ) {

                // Get the Unit by Matching the Temporary Pattern
                var units = $(this).data('unit');

                // Post Estimate Output
                $("form #estimation").val( eightSqm[ units ] ); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Temporary Pattern is currently my array that being used here. I just need to figure out what was the correct condition i need to use to make my calculation work using my "Main pattern". Sorry Im noob here...

Here's my sample full code.

[Calculator in jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/4kpc4he5/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figure out what was the issue. Here's my final solution over this calculator.

```
$("form fieldset").each(function (i) {
    i = i+1;
    $(this).addClass("item"+i);

    var prices = [
        ["kr 160 000,-", "kr 210 000,-", "kr 260 000,-", "kr 310 000,-", "kr 370 000,-"],
        ["kr 190 000,-", "kr 250 000,-", "kr 320 000,-", "kr 380 000,-", "kr 440 000,-"],
        ["kr 250 000,-", "kr 310 000,-", "kr 400 000,-", "kr 480 000,-", "kr 560 000,-"]
    ];

    r = 1;
    c = 2;

    $('.item'+i+' input').bind('change', function (){
        r = $('input[name=standard]:checked').val();
        c = $('input[name=size]:checked').val();

        $("form #estimation").val( prices[r][c] ); 
    });
});
```

Please check the actual code and functions here in my [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/wre2vzuo/4/).